# How to achieve a (almost) full view uitableview that can scroll past the last cell and show further elements in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I have attached the below image because it describes my problem better than words:

[image]

So basically, I need the Title/Subtitles part at the top to always be static, after that a dynamic `UITableView` which will have a lot of cells (mostly will fill the rest of the screen), and then after that a few additional elements such as a Map View and etc.

I'm using storyboards/xibs for this so it was also an issue of how to constraint everything in the designer properly. Would a stack or scroll view be appropriate for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can take two paths to achieve this.

The first is to create a custom cell containing the map and another containing the "Paragraph of text" thing.
Then you only need to push the cells at the end of the original data source.
Keep in mind that you need to add this cells to the RowsInSection function.

The other way is add a custom footer view to the tableView.
You can create a custom UIView containing the map an other info and then tell the table to take the custom view as footer:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = customView
```

Comment: That's what my initial idea for this was but I started questioning myself if it's the proper route as far as standards and good practices go and also if I might be missing a better solution. In this case that's what I'll follow through with, thank you

Comment: @sc00ctbr you are welcome, If you need more help in some ios-swift related problem do not hesitate to send me a message.